# How is the weight of a hanging block communicated to a scale?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

I read in a physics text (Tipler, Physics for Scientists and Engineers, 5th ed.) that if we have a scale, and on the scale is a hollow box of mass $M$, and inside the box is a block of mass m hanging from the ceiling by a string, the reading on the scale will be $(m + M)g$. I.e. the scale registers the weights of the box and the block.

I'm trying to convince myself why this should be true and I can't do it. I don't see a physical mechanism through which the weight of the hanging block can possibly be communicated to the scale.

My understanding of this type of scale is that it doesn't measure the weight per se but the normal force, which are not strictly the same but for most purposes can be treated as such. But I can't come up with any way by which the block's weight manifests as something the scale would have to push up against as a normal force.

My only semi-plausible idea is that the block is displacing a volume of air at a non-zero height, which might mean the pressure at the floor of the box is now slightly greater than it would be if the block were on the ground. But that doesn't seem promising to me.

Comment: Have you ever lifted an object while standing on a bathroom scale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hanging weight *pulls down* on the larger one enclosing it, with a force that equals its weight, and this adds to the weight or gravitational force of the larger mass.

Consequently, the scale reads the normal force of the larger and smaller masses combined.

If the inner mass $m$ has a string holding it up, the tension in the string is ${\bf T}=m{\bf g}$. Since this string is "transmitting" to the outer block mass $M$ a force pulling it down $\bf T$, then the total gravitational force/weight of the system is $${\bf T}+M{\bf g}={\bf N}$$ then
$$\implies {\bf N}=(m+M){\bf g}$$ where $\bf N$ is the normal force, or the force recorded by the scale. This is the weight of the whole system.